# Chef: How to see how cookbook from chef supermarket looks like

Tags: chef-infra

I'm new to chef. I'm now learning to get a recipe from the chef supermarket and starting it in a local vagrant box. It works fine but I don't know how my recipe which I'v 'pulled' looks like.

So I've edited metadata.rb inside my cookbook and added:

```
depends 'selinux', '~> 0.9'
```

I'm able to go to the chefsupermarket online and read the documentation. But is there wa way to see where the content of this 'pull' is?
In default.rb I set `include_recipe 'selinux::permissive'` to include it on my next `kitchen converge`. But I'm following a tutorial and practically everything is going fine. But it's more about the fact to understand it.

- How do I know how the cookbook of selinux looks
- How do I know how I have to describe the include_recipe statement in
  metadata.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click the `Download Cookbook` button on the right to download an archive of the cookbook or the `View Source` button to view the code on GitHub (though beware that you are seeing the master branch by default which might not match the latest release).